# Recalculate the position of a larger object to re-align two different sized objects after rotation

Tags: php, math, ffmpeg, geometry, imagemagick

I have 2 images I am placing on top of a 1080X1920 canvas.

One is a rectangle that is 800x400 and it is sitting on the 1080X1920 canvas with top left coordinates of x=140 and y=1200

[image]

Then I have another image that is the same size of the canvas 1080X1920, but also has a rectangle on it at the exact same coordinates as the first rectangle.  I am overlaying this 1080X1920 image at x=0 and y=0 on the canvas so that the rectangle already in this image lines up perfectly with the rectangle that is already placed on the canvas.

[image]

My problem is, I need to apply a rotation to both of these and the black and red rectangles need to match up in positioning AFTER the rotation is applied.  Could be any rotation, but let's say it is a 15 degree rotation.

When each element is placed on the canvas and then the 15 degree rotation is applied, the rectangles no longer align because of the difference in image size and the offset in rotation as they both rotate around the center point which looks to be my only option in this case.

[image]

So I am hoping to sort out a formula I can use that would rectify the positioning of the 1080X1920 image so that the object already embedded in that image lines up with separately overlaid image.

There are of course other ways to deal with this problem, but right now, they would make things quite a bit more difficult, so I wanted to see if this was possible to calculate first.

I have tried several ways to calculate this, but am not super mathematically proficient, so I am grasping at straws at best.

Oh and because I am not extremely mathematically proficient, any dumbing-down of mathematical terms is appreciated. ;)

Oh and possibly this post answers this question, but I can't wrap my head around whether or not it does, so if someone can let me know if it does, I will try harder to understand and apply it to my particular case.

[How to recalculate the coordinates of a point after scaling and rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49091198/how-to-recalculate-the-coordinates-of-a-point-after-scaling-and-rotation)

Comment: Are you asking how to precisely position a rotated 800x400 image onto a similarly rotated 1080x1920 image by specifying the location of the upper-left corner of the 800x400 relative to that of the 1080x1920 image? And to do this in FFmpeg programatically?

Comment: @Kesh Well, while this has to do with ffmpeg, I don't need to know how to do it in ffmpeg.  Likely the calculations will be in PHP.  Just need the formula really (as the dimensions will be dynamic.)  At the core, however, if you look at the third image, I need to determine how much to shift the black box to match the pos of the red box.  Does that make sense?  I will rotate both and then need to reposition the black so it is in the exact same position as the red.

Comment: It is critical to know which agent (ffmpeg/imagemagick/php/etc.) is performing the rotation. For example, you don't need to be bothered with spatial transformation matrix if it is done with FFmpeg `rotate` filter.

Comment: @kesh Yeah I am using the rotate filter, but my specs are just the rectangle by itself.  i.e. width 800x400 and rotated 15 degrees. One moment thought... you might have given me an idea.

Comment: @kesh My issue is, I am using drawtext to animate text onto the full sized 1080x1920 canvas so it might fly in from the top, sides, left etc. but appear to be sitting inside one of those boxes.  If I am placing the drawtext based on the canvas size, but need to rotate it based on the final position (appearing it sits inside of the box).  I could fly the text into the box first, but then it won't fly over the rest of the canvas, it will just appear at the edges of the box.

Comment: The math would likely be a trigonometric equation.  But I do not know what data points you have.   You could probably do this in PHP using `imagerotate()` and `imagecopymerge()`  Get me the data points and I'll write the PHP code for you.

Comment: Shift the origin to the center of the object from the top left corner of the background. Then rotate the object corners about the center (new origin). Then shift the origin back to the top left corner again. So that is one translate, one rotation and then one translate

Answer (score 0):

Any rotation is done around a "center of rotation". You don't tell the centers you use, but they can be:

- Center of the canvas.
- Center of each image (middle point of its four corners),
- Some corner.
- Any other point.

If both rotations are *not* the same, then there's not possible match.

It seems you use the center of each image. Then, to match the second rectangle to the first one, after you rotate the first image you must do **in this order**:

1. Translate the second image so its center of rotation is exactly the
   same as the center of rotation of the first image. The *vector* of translation is the coordinates difference for X,Y centers.
2. Rotate the second image with the same angle as the first image rotation.

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to tracking where the original (0,0) points are on the two images after rotation.

Let's define the problem a bit cleaner:

- `red.png`: 800x400
- `black.png`: 1080X1920
- rotate both by 15° (or θ = 15 * π/180) with `rotate` filter (assuming the actual values are within -90° and 90°)
- how to place a rotated red.png on rotated black.png at the ORIGINAL top-left coordinates (x=140,y=120)

Consider 2 FFmpeg rotation commands:

```
ffmpeg red.png -vf rotate=15*PI/180:ow=hypot(iw\\,ih):oh=ow -frames:v 1 red_rotated.png

ffmpeg black.png -vf rotate=15*PI/180 -frames:v 1 black_rotated.png
```

Note that `red_rotated.png` is enlarged to inscribe the red rectangle while `black_rotated.png` maintains the same size. Now, the question is "where are the original top-left corner now?"

`red_rotated.png`:

- `0 < θ < π/2` cases: `(xr,yr) = (h sin(θ), 0)`
- `-π/2 < θ < 0` cases: `(xr,yr) = (0, w sin(θ))`

`black_rotated.png`: Same as `red_rotated.png` but now cropped to the original size

- new size: `ow = w cos(θ) + h sin(|θ|)`, `oh = w sin(|θ|) + h cos(θ)`
- size delta: `dw = (ow - w)/2`, `dh = (oh - h)/2`
- `0 < θ < π/2` cases: `(xb, yb) = (h sin(-θ) - dw, -dh)`
- `-π/2 < θ < 0` cases: `(xb, yb) = (-dw, w sin(θ) - dh)`

Now, where is the insertion coordinate (x,y) = (140,120) on `black_rotated.png`:

1. rotate wrt the original corner: `(x1,y1) = (x cos(θ) - y sin(θ), x sin(θ) + y cos(θ)`
2. shift wrt the new black corner: `(x2,y2) = (x1 + xb, y1 + yb)`
3. shift wrt the new red corner: `(x3,y3) = (x2 - xr, y2 - yr)`

Accordingly overlaying `red_rotated.png` with the offset `(x3,y3)` onto `black_rotated.png` should get you the results you want.

Disclaimer: I have not verified my math, but this is should be a good starting point.

Comment: Bless you for giving this a go.  I thought I was on my own, so I started creating an oversized canvas so I could get the box into the center of it, rotate it and then crop it back which actually is kind of working, but not super ideal.  Let me play with yours and see if I can sort it out.  Let me know if you do any paid consulting as I might need more help with this.

Comment: sorry, but when you say shift wrt what does the wrt stand for?

Comment: wrt=with respect to

Comment: What could help you visualize this problem better is to draw 4 rectangles using a full printer paper: black before & after rotation (rotated at the center) and red before and after (rotate & expand) placed on the correct location on the rotated black... ok maybe not so easy to put it in words...